# postgresql unable to create table in schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating schema/db/... with this script:

```
CREATE ROLE testuser LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE TABLESPACE testtablespace OWNER testuser LOCATION '/pgdata/pg94/testtablespace';
CREATE SCHEMA testschema;
ALTER SCHEMA testschema OWNER TO testuser;
CREATE DATABASE testdb WITH TABLESPACE testtablespace ENCODING 'UNICODE' LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C' TEMPLATE template0 OWNER testuser;
ALTER DATABASE testdb SET search_path TO testschema, public;
ALTER ROLE testuser SET search_path TO testschema, public;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE testdb TO testuser;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA testschema TO testuser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA testschema TO testuser;
ALTER ROLE testuser SET default_tablespace = testtablespace;
```

when I log in with command `psql -U testuser testdb` and execute comand `select schema_name from information_schema.schemata ;`. What is worse I can't create table within this schema

```
testdb=> create table testschema.test (test varchar(10));
ERROR:  schema "testschema" does not exist
```

please what should I configure to view schema and also create tables in int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE SCHEMA` always applies to current database. You have created `testschema` in current database (probably `postgres`), not in `testdb`. 
You should connect to `testdb` and then create new schemas.

Comment: Is there way how to create schema for some db without connecting to that db? Something like create schema testdb.testschema ?

Comment: I'm affraid it's impossible. You can check [the syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createschema.html).